# JS file revisions using Gulp

Tags: gulp

I am writing my first gulp file i am trying to add a revision with each an every gulp build as follows

`<script type='text/javascript' src='js.app.js?{gulp_generated_random_number}'></script>`

Any ideas?

Comment: try this: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-template

Comment: you could use this as a reference: https://github.com/bustardcelly/gulp-rev-append

Comment: also if you haven't done these yet: https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook

Comment: and this: https://github.com/substack/stream-adventure